# Presidential cryptic clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

Single cryptic clue

> President's family happiest underground [8]

better cryptic clue for this after help in comments below

> President's family is fictional creature [8]

Comment: (The definition part of a cryptic clue should be, well, a *definition*, something you might find as a clue in a traditional crossword puzzle.  "Fond of Puzzling" might be a way to describe me but it's not a fair cryptic *definition* for me; among other things, "fond of Puzzling" is an adjectival phrase, so must clue something that's an adjective, not a noun. ***Define*** it, don't merely ***describe*** it.)

Comment: @Rubio - thanks so much for the helpful comment. I really appreciate it. I can thus see that 'President's family is reduced in stature' would also not be a good clue, but perhaps 'President's family is fictional creature' or 'President's family is a fantasy creation' is better. - and thanks again for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Trumpkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trumpkin)

Explanation

> "President's family" could be interpreted as *Trump kin*. 
>  Trumpkin is a dwarf from the Chronicles of Narnia series and dwarfs are generally skilled in mining (underground). This may be where we say they are happiest (think of Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs and how happy they were to work in the mine). 
>   Alternatively, Trumpkin the character is one of the "Old Narnian" underground and membership of this underground movement allows him *"to escape harassment from the Telmarine usurpers of Narnia"* suggesting that it is where he would be the happiest

Comment: How do you match the word "happiest"?

Comment: It seems, from the source provided, that membership of this underground movement allows him *"to escape harassment from the Telmarine usurpers of Narnia"* suggesting that it is where he would be the happiest. I've edited my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: Great job - you have the correct answer, but in the explanation rot13(gurer vf nabgure ernfba sbe 'unccvrfg haqretebhaq' nygubhtu V yvxr lbhe vagrcergngvba. gurer vf n (cbffvoyl fvzcyre) nygreangvir rkcynangvba.).... you are very close to 100% correct..

Comment: @hexomino I don't see Trumpkin happy anywhere! Plus this kind of puzzle usually cut the beginning/middle/end of the solution between the terms (so maybe the first part is juste rot13("Gehzc")?)

Comment: Ok so to try to help finish this off - what is the 'answer', apart from being part of the underground???

Comment: @tom I've edited my answer to include an alternative interpretation. Not sure if closer or further away.

Comment: @hexomino no, sorry nice idea, but actually further away... in the world of Naria how else might the 'answer' be descirbed ---

Comment: @tom I've changed it one more time. Still not completely sure.

Comment: @hexomino - great yes - well done!!! with no further ado Green Token :-) (you got upvoted by me ages ago) - (rot13)Gur cbvag bs 'unccvrfg haqretebhaq' jnf gb zrnag gb or n pyhr gb qenjirf jbexvat/yvivat haqretebhaq, ohg lbhe guvat nobhg gur haqretebhaq erfvfgnapr va Aneavn jnf irel tbbq nf jryy.